# using deep selector with less css

Tags: vue.js, less, vue-component, webpack-style-loader

I am using less css in my vue components.
Some of my components require the use of '>>>' deep selector for elements that I add programatically. However I get 'Unrecognised input' error when I do so.

I want to use less syntax to import variable for colors, font-size, etc. to keep those core variable in one file and use them in all of my components.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: `>>>` - strictly speaking it's not a CSS. For more details see https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2623.

Comment: Thank you. That resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) in the Vue Loader docs, if your preprocessor does not allow `>>>` you can use `::v-deep`, which should be ignored by the preprocessor because it is syntactically valid CSS.